# php preg_replace string extract

Tags: php, regex

Original regexp:

```
$str = '"foo" <bar@baz.com>';
preg_replace('/\s(<.*?>)|"/', '', $str);
```

I would like to extract the following:

```
"foo" <bar@baz.com> extract only => foo
<bar@baz.com>       extract only => <bar@baz.com>
"" <bar@baz.com>    extract only => <bar@baz.com>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you clarify what you are actually trying to do here? because if you are trying to *get* the value, preg_replace() isn't really the right function for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to require something inside the quotes when you do the replace.

```
$str = '"foo" <bar@baz.com>';
preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s(<.*?>)/', '$1', $str);
preg_replace('/""\s(<.*?>)/', '$1', $str);
```

Try that. It should leave the address alone if there's no quoted name before it.

**Edit:** Based on your new example inputs and outputs, try this:

```
$str = '"foo" <bar@baz.com>';
preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s(<.*?>)/', '$1', $str);
preg_replace('/(?:""\s)?(<.*?>)/', '$1', $str);
```

It should have the following input/output results:

```
"foo" <bar@baz.com>  -> foo
"" <bar@baz.com>     -> <bar@baz.com>
<bar@baz.com>        -> <bar@baz.com>
```

Comment: is there a way to extract the name only if between quotes, and not both?

Comment: @Mike - Not sure I understand. Could you explain what you mean by that? The above code should turn `"foo" <bar@baz.com>` into `foo`, and `"" <bar@baz.com>` into `<bar@baz.com>`.

Comment: you should be using preg_match instead of preg_replace...I mean yah it "works" but that's not really what preg_replace was designed for..

Comment: @Crayon - Depends on what he's trying to do. I could go either way with it, especially since preg_replace works without too much difficulty. If you want a one-liner, it's a job for preg_match or preg_replace_callback. Many roads to the same place. :)

Comment: @Mike: Yes, like I said, it "works".  But why take the long and winding path over the straight?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so it looks like you are wanting to *get* a value, rather than *replace* a value, so you should be using preg_match, not preg_replace (though technically you *could* use preg_replace in a round-about way...)

```
preg_match('~(?:"([^"]*)")?\s*(.*)~',$str,$match);
$var = ($match[1])? $match[1] : $match[2];
```